# Laravel _ Vue.js(SPA) composer package

Tags: laravel, vue.js, composer, package

Есть проблема. Есть уже готовая админка на laravel+vue.js, выполнена в виде СПА.

Мне нужно разработать composer package с определенным функционалом.

И сама проблема связанна с роутингом во vue.js

Как мне подключить роуты пакета(роуты не ларавелевские, а SPA-шные) к роутам уже существующего приложения?

Вот уже существующие роуты:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/admin/403',
    name: '403',
    component: Forbidden,
},
{
    path: '/admin/404',
    name: '404',
    component: NotFound,
},
{
    path: '/admin/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
},
{
    path: '/admin/',
    component: Layout,
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard.index',
            component: Dashboard
        },
    ]
},
```

];

К ним нужно подтянуть роуты пакета (с проверкой авторизации)